# Cast error passing a void function with namespace

Tags: c++, c, casting, mongoose-web-server

I'm trying to wrap, in a C++ class, a server that I wrote using [mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose) (a C library). The problem is that I'm trying to pass the function `ev_handler` to the `mg_create_server()`, which create the instance of the server in mongoose. But it gives a casting error I believe:

```
src/Server.cpp:16:44: error: cannot convert 'Server::ev_handler' from
type 'int (Server::)(mg_connection*, mg_event)' to type 'mg_handler_t
{aka int (*)(mg_connection*, mg_event)}'   server =
mg_create_server(NULL, ev_handler);
```

I tried to make `ev_handler` static but it has `send_index_page(conn)` that has to be inside the wrapper class.

```
void Server::start() {
        struct mg_server *server;
        int numberOfObjects;
        _application = new Application();
        _application->start();

        // Create and configure the server
        server = mg_create_server(NULL, ev_handler);

//... more code here ...
}

int Server::ev_handler(struct mg_connection *conn, enum mg_event ev) {
                switch (ev) {
                        case MG_AUTH:     return MG_TRUE;
                        case MG_REQUEST:  return send_index_page(conn);
                        default:          return MG_FALSE;
                }
}
```

Comment: Please do not creatively work around not able to mention "problem" in a title. *Describe the problem*, don't say you "have a problem". (This is frowned upon because *everyone* here Has A Problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're passing a C++ member function to parameter that wants a free function pointer.

Mongoose is a C API and all of its callback parameters are C style functions, which in C++ are free (not member) functions.

A member function pointer is different from a free function pointer in that it needs the `this` , or the object on which the method is being called, in order to be called.

In your case, you are passing a member function pointer on the `Server` class.

When interacting which C APIs, it's common to pass a `void*` context object which is then passed to the callback.  You then pass a pointer to a free function or a static class method (which has no `this` and can therefore work with C APIs).  When the callback is invoked, you then cast the context object to the correct type and call a member function to get back into the object context.  I can't see any such facility in Mongoose.  Maybe it's there and I'm just not finding it.

You may want to try the already exising Mongoose C++ which forks the original Mongoose project to work better with C++: https://github.com/Gregwar/mongoose-cpp

Comment: I looked to mongoose-cpp, but it use a 2 years old mongoose.

Answer (score 2):

The callback needs to be static, then you should use a static stub to redirect to the class instance.

Storing the instance of your class in `server_param` attribute of `mg_server` will allow to get it back in a static stub and forward it to this instance.

This could be achieve like this :

```
class Server
{
public: 
        void start() { 
             mg_create_server(this, ev_handlerStub); 
        }
        static int ev_handlerStub(struct mg_connection *conn, enum mg_event ev) {
             ((Server*)conn->server_param)->ev_handler(conn, ev);
        }
        int ev_handler(struct mg_connection *conn, enum mg_event ev) {
             // job to do with the class instance
        }
 };
```

Proceeding like this, allow access to class instance inside its `ev_handler` method.